# Displaying data in a modal using functional Reactjs approach partly working

Tags: reactjs

I used the **class approach method** as per code below to display a unique modal record when button is clicked
 and its working fine and good.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21" },
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78" },
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90" },
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" },
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19" },
        { name: "tom", Age: "89" }
      ],


      currentRec: undefined,
    };
    this.viewData = this.viewData.bind(this);
  }

 viewData(i){
    this.setState({ currentRec: i });
    console.log(`Selected record index: ${i}`);
   alert(`Selected record index: ${i}`);
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <div className="container">

        <div>
          <h3>List of Records</h3>
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age}{" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => { this.viewData(i); }}
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#myModal"
                >
                  view from Modal
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="modal" id="myModal">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h4 className="modal-title">Show Records in Modal</h4>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  &times;
                </button>
              </div>

              {this.state.currentRec !== undefined && 
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    Name: {this.state.rec[this.state.currentRec].name} <br />
                    Age: {this.state.rec[this.state.currentRec].Age} <br />

                  </div>}

              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Close
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is my issue:** I now want to rewrite it using functional approach.

when I run the functional code the records gets displayed fine but when I clicked the modal button to display records of each modal, no
result or data is displayed in the modal. I think the function below is not responding to click event

```
function viewData(i){
    setcurrentRec({ currentRec: i });
    console.log(`Selected record index: ${i}`);
   alert(`Selected record index: ${i}`);
  }
```

**here is the functional code**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Application (){

//const currentRec = undefined;
const [currentRec, setcurrentRec] = useState(undefined);

const rec = 
[
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21" },
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78" },
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90" },
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" },
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19" },
        { name: "tom", Age: "89" }
      ];

 function viewData(i){
    setcurrentRec({ currentRec: i });
    console.log(`Selected record index: ${i}`);
   alert(`Selected record index: ${i}`);
  }

    return (
      <div className="container">

        <div>
          <h3>List of Records</h3>
          <ul>
            {rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age}{" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => {viewData(i); }}
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#myModal"
                >
                  view from Modal
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="modal" id="myModal">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h4 className="modal-title">Show Records in Modal</h4>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  &times;
                </button>
              </div>

              {currentRec !== undefined && 
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    Name: {rec[currentRec].name} <br />
                    Age: {rec[currentRec].Age} <br />

                  </div>}

              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Close
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: First of all call  `setcurrentRec(i);`
Then you can use inline function only like  `onClick={() => { setcurrentRec(i); }}`
and you should use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hooks for such requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the index value in `currenctRec` and not `{ currentRec : i }`, As you are saving `setcurrentRec({ currentRec: i })` , it is not. finding. the index value rather it is getting object which is saving index value hence your code `{rec[currentRec].name}` is not working. Please find the fixed code below :

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-davinci-vgm0u?file=/src/Application.js:1731-1753